# Return all elements except for a specific element that also has no value

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to linq to xml (linq to anything, for that matter), and I'm trying to count the number of elements in an xml file but exclude some. Here's an example:

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
      <binding>paperback</binding>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
      <binding></binding>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Given the above xml, I'd like to return all elements except for the  element that has no value. So the end count in this case would be 16 because I don't want to count the empty element.

Comment: When you say element with no value. What do you mean? binding is an element and does not have a value. Do you mean a book element?

Comment: I mean a specific element, in this case, <binding>. As you can see in my xml, the second book has a <binding> element with no value. I want to return everything but that one. And let's say that the xml is bigger with thousands of books, I want to return all elements except for all of the <binding> elements that have no value. So the pseudocode might be "read xml file minus element name "binding" where value is empty".

Comment: I see. Any of the solutions below would work. However, if you think an element might contain white spaces then you need to use my version below (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace). If you need both the elements and their count, then you should use .ToList() and then access the .Count property.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int count  = XDocument.Load(@"C:\books.xml")
            .Descendants()
            .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Value))
            .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try  but this would work:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");
var count = xDoc.Descendants()
            .Count(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)x));
```

If you want elements just use `Where` instead of `Count`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with using all the help. Not sure if it's very efficient, but it works:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\books.xml");
var elementList = doc.Descendants().ToList();
int count = elementList.Count();
count -= elementList.Where(x => x.Name == "binding" && String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value)).Count();
```

Comment: If your XML content is not very large, this would be Ok in terms of performance.